# Getting a Sharepoint List Fields that are common to all content types contained in the list

Tags: csom, content-type, sharepoint-fields, list-column

I'm trying to get the list fields shared by all the content types in said List.
After getting the List by its Title, I used the Fields property to get all the fields in the List:

```
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('list Title');
clientContext.Load(list);
FieldCollection listFields = list.Fields;
clientContext.Load(listFields);
```

The problem is I only want the ones shared by all content types in the list.
Is there a way to get them without having to go through all the content types and their respective Fields and comparing them to get the one in common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't tell which Content Type it is from Field object